# Excel VBA - Close workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I am importing a worksheet from another workbook to my current workbook. After I complete importing the worksheet, I want to close that other workbook. The code I am using gives the error **Run-time error 9': Subscript out of range**.

```
Sub ImportWorksheet(MyPath As String, wbName As String)

ControlFile = ActiveWorkbook.Name
Workbooks.Open Filename:=MyPath
Sheets(1).Copy After:=Workbooks(ControlFile).Sheets(1)
ActiveSheet.Name = wbName
Workbooks(MyPath).Close SaveChanges:=False
Windows(ControlFile).Activate

End Sub
```

I also tried using

```
Windows(MyPath).Activate
ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
```

But I get the same error.

Comment: I'm guessing `MyPath` is a file path, which works fine when you're opening a workbook by it's `Filename`, but when using `Workbooks().Close` you need to list the workbook's **name**, not it's path. Try using `Workbooks(Dir(MyPath)).Close SaveChanges:=False`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to assign variable, it removes any confusion.

```
Sub ImportWorksheet(MyPath As String, wbName As String)


Dim Owb As Workbook
Dim Nwb As Workbook

Set Owb = ThisWorkbook
Set Nwb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=MyPath)

Nwb.Sheets(1).Copy after:=Owb.Sheets(1)
Owb.Sheets(2).Name = wbName

Nwb.Close False
Owb.Activate

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Since Open method of Workbooks object returns a Workbook object you can reference the opened workbook:

```
Sub ImportWorksheet(MyPath As String, wbName As String)
    ControlFile = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    With Workbooks.Open(Filename:=MyPath)
        .Sheets(1).Copy After:=Workbooks(ControlFile).Sheets(1)
        .Sheets(2).Name = wbName
        .Close SaveChanges:=False 
    End With 
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Workbooks(strTargetFileName).Close SaveChanges:=False
```